# SAT Solver: SAT4J - more examples?

Tags: solver, sat, sat4j

I haven't used before a SAT solver, so I started to learn how to use SAT4J. Mostly, I am using its API, but I am finding hard to understand sometimes what some arguments (in classes or methods) mean or what their format/type is acceptable. For example:

```
public BinaryClause(IVecInt ps, ILits voc)
```

My question is if there are some usage examples, which can help me more in understanding the implemented features in SAT4j?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find some usage examples of most features in the unit tests:
http://www.sat4j.org/maven234/org.ow2.sat4j.core/xref-test/index.html

BinaryClause class is not meant to be used by end users:
http://www.sat4j.org/maven234/org.ow2.sat4j.core/apidocs/index.html

We try to maintain user level doc up to date. The developer level may change over time, to may lack documentation.

Comment: it's my pleasure to get a reply from you. Thank you. I didn't know about these unit tests. They seem quite helpful for me! Thank you, again.